# Python Error: type object 'str' has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, api

I am providing an user input to my python script and it is throwing the error:

File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\gtech\ads\ds\histconv\parsers.py", line 34, in raw_input_to_unicode
    return str.decode(input_string, sys.stdin.encoding or
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'decode

and here is the code where i am handling the input string

```
def raw_input_to_unicode(input_string):

    return str.decode(input_string, sys.stdin.encoding or
              locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

Comment: This looks like Python-2.x code, since Python-3.x, a `str` has no `.decode()` anymore.

Comment: So, str(input_string) will work?

Comment: no, since it is Python-2.x, it will probably fail on multiple issues. Python-2.x and Python-3.x are not "compatible" with each other (personally I see these as two separate, but related languages). Therefore it is advisable not to run Python-2.x software with a 3.x interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.x strings are usually unicodes

If you get your string from input() function it sure is unicode